# If I take a raw pointer of a unique_ptr and then use reset, is the raw pointer still guaranteed to be valid?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Eg I'm pretty sure this works.

```
int foo = 51;
int* bar = &foo;
foo = 3;
```

So bar is still valid, and `*bar == 3`.

What about if we say

```
std::unique_ptr<int> foo(new int(51));  // should probably use make_unique
int* bar = foo.get();
foo.reset(new int(3));
```

Am I guaranteed that `*bar == 3`?
Or am I causing undefined behavior by continuing to reference bar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, not at all. You will get undefined behaviour, as the raw pointer managed by the `unique_ptr` is changed by the `reset`. In fact, the `unique_ptr` deletes the managed pointer and reallocates a new one, so your old pointer will keep pointing to the old address, which is no longer valid. Your code is equivalent to this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int* managed = new int(51); // equivalent to unique_ptr(new int(51));
    int* bar = managed; // equivalent of unique_ptr::get
    delete managed; managed = new int(3); // equivalent to unique_ptr::reset(new int(3))
    std::cout << *bar << std::endl; // Wrong!!! Undefined behaviour, bar is dangling!
}
```

Your first code snippet is indeed correct, since you are not changing any address there, you are just changing the variable the pointer points to, so of course dereferencing the pointer will get you the updated value.

Answer (score 9):

No, if you reset a `unique_ptr`, it will delete the pointer it owns.

You can do:

```
int* bar = foo.release();
```

This causes `foo` to give up ownership of its pointer and return it.

Comment: If I set `bar = foo.get()` and then later decide that I'm going to change foo, can I just call `foo.release()` and let bar assume ownership without explicit assignment? I can't really think of a use-case, but I'm curious if that will work correctly.

Comment: @wrhall: No, you cannot. That would be tremendously unsafe. The unique_ptr *always* owns the pointer. That's it's sole purpose. You can only prevent that by using `release()`, which is a terrible function that you should never call.

Comment: @Puppy even if it's bad practice, is it technically correct? Looking at the documentation, it seems that `release()` *Releases the ownership of the managed object if any. get() returns `nullptr` after the call.* So it looks to me that `release()` really does `return managed_ptr;` and marks the `unique_ptr` as "non-managing", so future `get()` return `nullptr`. Do you know if this is indeed the case?

Comment: Yes, that is what `release()` does. And yes, if you `get()` the pointer first and then `release()` it later, your pointer will still be valid (provided the `unique_ptr` was not changed prior to the `release()`).

Answer (score 0):

No, std::unique_ptr.reset will delete the existing pointer.

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/reset/

For your purpuse use [release](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/release/).